# How to format a date after subtracting in Python?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now().today()
```

I need to subtract from today, so I did as follows:

```
date_of_sale = compare1.date_of_sale
calculate_days = today.date() - date_of_sale
print (unicode(calculate_days1)
```

And then I need to print out and give me the correct date, but the formatting is not good:

```
u'3 days, 0:00:00'
```

I need to show '3 days' only.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: the `days` part and comma is not guaranteed to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). If you only need the days portion, format this yourself:

```
print('{} days'.format(calculate_days1.days))
```